# How to convert YOLOv8 raw output to bounding box coordinates and class probabilities

Tags: python, tensorflow-lite, yolo, yolov8, tflite

I trained a custom object detection model using `ultralytics` and converted it to Tensorflow Lite format.

Now when I make a prediction for an image (640x640x3) using the tflite model, the result is a tensor of the shape [1, 7, 8400].

Here is my code:

[image]

I found out that in [1, 7, 8400]:

- 1 - is batch size
- 7 - 4  bounding box coordinates(x_center, y_center, width, height) + 3 probability each class
- 8400 - 640 pixels/8 =80; 80x80=**6400**. 640 pixels/16=40; 40x40= **1600**. 640 pixels/32=20; 20x20=**400**. **6400+1600+400=8400**

I am looking for a easy way to decode this tensor to bounding box coordinates and class probabilities.